# Viele oder vieles?

Tags: translation, word-choice, pronoun, declension

Was soll ich sagen...

> Hast du heute ***viele*** {oder} ***vieles*** geplant?

Comment: Without any context we can’t give you an answer. »Hast du viel geplant?« would be also possible.

Comment: The correct form of _viel_ depends on the noun which it qualifies.

Comment: @User26328 In the current example, it doesn't qualify anything

Comment: "Do you have a lot planned today" würde ich sagen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ohne weiteren Kontext ist die Form *viele* in dem Fall nicht korrekt (siehe weiter unten). Du kannst fragen:

> Hast du heute viel geplant?

oder

> Hast du heute vieles geplant?

Der Unterschied zwischen *viel* und *vieles* ist eher subtil. Mit *vieles/weniges* werden vorzugsweise mehrere einzelne Dinge aus einer größeren Menge bezeichnet. Beispiele:

> Ich habe heute eine Nachrichtensendung auf Französisch gesehen, aber leider nur weniges verstanden.
>
> Wir waren drei Wochen im Urlaub; deswegen ist vieles im Kühlschrank verdorben.

**Nachtrag zu *viele***

Das *viele* könnte in diesem Satz nur dann alleine stehen, wenn es sich auf etwas zuvor Gesagte bezieht. Beispielsweise:

> - Ich habe Äpfel gekauft.
> - Und, hast du heute schon viele gegessen? (*alternativ:* Hast du heute schon viel davon gegessen?)

Comment: Danke. Sehr hilfreich