# "Viel" vs "vieles" in diesem Satz

Tags: adjective, declension, adjective-ending

Im folgenden Satz

> Wie Kerstin Cuhls berichtet, wird durch moderne Kommunikationsmittel
> vieles möglich

wieso ist es "vieles" und nicht "viel"?  Ich habe gelesen, dass manchmal "vieles" sich auf "viele unspezifische Dinge" beziehen kann.  Ist das der Fall hier?

(Eine zusätzliche Frage, wenn ich bitten darf: ich glaube, dass in meinem Satz "viele unspezifische" richtig ist, d.h., dass die Deklination anders als mit dem Artikel "die" ("die unspezifischen Dinge") ist.  Wie funktionert die Deklination mit "viel/e"?

Comment: Related answer: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/37284/42116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Der angegebene Beispielsatz ist richtig. "viele unspezifische Dinge" wäre Plural und Plural wird nur bei *zählbaren* Dingen verwendet. Hier wird aber von "etwas Unzählbares" (also Singular) gesprochen, weshalb "vieles" (Singular) korrekt ist. ("Dinge" - jede Art von Dingen, auch unspezifische - kann man zählen, "das Unspezifische" nicht.) Das sieht man nicht nur an der Endung von "vieles", sondern auch an dem verwendeten Verb ("wird"), welches ebenfalls im Singular steht.

> ..., (es) *wird* viel*es* möglich.

Würden hier "Dinge" (also Plural) impliziert, dann müßte der Satz etwa lauten:

> ..., (es) *werden* viel*e* möglich.

Da aber, wie oben gesagt, unzählbare Dinge ("Unzählbares") im Singular stehen, ist die erste Variante richtig.

Edit: der Unterschied zwischen "vieles" und "viel" ist subtil: "vieles" ist die Form, die entsteht, wenn man von "das Viele" (also ein substantiviertes Adjektiv) den Artikel wegläßt. "vieles" ist zwar selbst unzählbar, besteht aber aus Zählbarem. Wenn "vieles möglich" ist, dann besteht das "Viele", das möglich ist, aus einzelnen Möglichkeiten: *vieles ist möglich, nämlich Möglichkeit A, Möglichkeit B, ...*. Hingegen ist "viel" nicht nur unzählbar, sondern besteht auch aus Unzählbarem. Es beschreibt eine Menge.

> Hier liegt viel (eine amorphe Menge) herum. Vieles davon (hier wird die Menge in einzelne, unterscheidbare Dinge getrennt) kann man wegwerfen, aber manches (wie "vieles", aber eben weniger) ist brauchbar.

Comment: Die Alternative in der Frage ist aber nicht "werden viele möglich", sondern "wird viel möglich". Und das ist ein semantisch korrekter Satz mit einer maximal leicht anderen Implikation als "wird vieles möglich."

Comment: Stimmt - ich habe mich auf den zweiten Teil der Frage konzentriert und den ersten dann vergessen - nachgetragen.